# std::ostream no deduce la conversión a std::string

Tags: c++, operador-de-conversión

Con este sencillo objeto:

```
struct S
{
    operator std::string() const { return "S"; }
};
```

Esperaba que este programa mostrase `S`:

```
int main()
{
    S s;
    std::cout << s;
    retutrn 0;
}
```

Sin embargo muestra una larga colección de errores de compilación relacionados con `std::ostream`, entre ellos:

> ```
> error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'S')
> |     std::cout << s;
> |     ~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~
> |          |       |
> |          |       S
> note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>&)'
> |     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
> |     ^~~~~~~~
> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note:   'S' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>'
> |     std::cout << s;
> |                  ^
> ```

Se queja de que `S` no deriva de `std::string`, si creo dicha relación:

```
struct S : public std::string
{
    operator std::string() const { return "S"; }
};
```

Desaparecen los errores, pero no muestra `S` por pantalla y el compilador da una alarma:

> ```
> warning: converting 'S' to a base class 'std::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'} will never use a type conversion operator [-Wclass-conversion]
> |     operator std::string() const { return "S"; }
> |     ^~~~~~~~
> ```

Indica que la conversión a la clase base **nunca** usará el operador de conversión. Obviamente, con una conversión explícita el problema desaparece:

```
S s;
std::cout << static_cast<std::string>(s); // llama al operador de conversión
```

También desaparece el problema con el operador de `std::ostream` adecuado:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const S &s)
{
    return o << static_cast<std::string>(s);
}
```

Pero me gustaría saber por qué `std::ostream` no es capaz de usar el operador de conversión a `std::string` del objeto `S`.

Answer (score 3):

Si observas las 18 sobrecargas que tiene [std::cout.operator<<](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) veras que ninguna tiene el **`std::string`** eso es por que la sobrecarga es externa a **`std::cout`**.

En realidad la sobrecarga esta en el archivo **`#include <string>`**, puedes ver la referencia de la sobrecarga **[AQUÍ](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt)**.

Ahora cuando tu haces **`std::cout << s`;** en realidad estas haciendo esto: **`std::cout.operator<<(s)`**, a continuación te muestro lo que hace **`std::cout`** cuando usas un **`std::string`** y porque lo que esperas no funciona:

Cuando tu haces esto:

```
std::string str = "algo";
std::cout << str;
```

C++ entiendo esto:

```
std::string str = "algo";
operator<<(std::cout, str);
```

Incluso si haces esto:

```
struct S s;
operator<<(std::cout, s);
```

Te dará error, por que C++ busca una sobrecarga específica y no genérica, pero como no existe la sobrecarga simplemente no puede realizar el **Cast** de **`struct S`** a **`std::string`**.

Por tanto, para que la expresión **`std::cout << s;`** sea válida tienes 3 maneras de hacerlo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    operator string() const { return "S"; };
};

int main()
{
    S s;

    // Primera forma: Cast explícito
    cout << (string)s;

    // Segunda forma: Cast explícito
    operator<<(cout, (string)s);

    // Tercera Forma: Cast implícito
    operator<<<string::value_type, string::traits_type, string::allocator_type>(cout, s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Denis agradezco mucho la respuesta, da gusto ver a un *recién llegado* con tanto nivel, espero verte participando en el sitio (y en la etiqueta) más a menudo. Dicho esto, agradecería que editases la resupuesta, no es cierto que `cout << s` falle por falta de sobrecargas (`struct S { operator int() const { return 42; } }; int main() { std::cout << S{}; return 0; }` funciona) es más correcto lo que dices después de "*busca la función específica, no la genérica*".

Answer (score 2):

El error se produce porque el operador de inserción que pretendes utilizar **es una plantilla**, y las funciones basadas en plantillas **no realizan conversiones implícitas**.

A una plantilla hay que pasarle un objeto que lo pueda relacionar directamente, es decir, que o bien sea del mismo tipo que el esperado o bien herede de el.

Es facil de demostrar. Para ello vamos primero a crear una colección de clases:

```
struct A
{
    int n;

    A(int n = 0) : n(n)
    { }
};

struct B : A
{
  B() : A(1)
  { }
};

struct C
{
    operator A() const
    { return A(2); }
};
```

Vamos a comprobar qué tal funciona la conversión:

```
void func1(A const& a)
{
    std::cout << "func1(" << a.n << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
  A a;
  B b;
  C c; 

  func1(a);
  func1(b);
  func1(c);
}
```

Podemos ver que el programa compila perfectamente y devuelve el resultado esperado:

```
012
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0aGftV76R9Ax8HkV).

Ahora vamos a reemplazar `A` por un tipo basado en plantillas:

```
template<class T>
struct AP
{
    int n;

    AP(int n = 0) : n(n)
    { }
};

struct BP : AP<int>
{
  BP() : AP<int>(1)
  { }
};

struct C
{
    operator AP<int>() const
    { return AP<int>(2); }
};
```

Bien, vamos a comprobar las conversiones:

```
template<class T>
void func(AP<T> const& a)
{
    std::cout << "func(" << a.n << ")\n";
}

int main()
{
  AP<int> a;
  BP b;
  C c;

  func(a);
  func(b);
  func(c);      // ERROR
}
```

Ahora el programa falla. Como era de esperar el compilador no tiene intención alguna de convertir `c` pese a que existe un operador de conversión adecuado.

Sin embargo, si *forzamos* la llamada para que trabaje con una especialización concreta entonces veremos que el error desaparece por arte de magia:

```
func<int>(c); // OK
```

Puedes ver este ejemplo funcionando [aqui](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zPhed69XhTkwzOCv)